# How to revert db changes made during unit tests?

Tags: android, testing

I need to go back to 'clean' db state after each test, what is the easiest way to revert changes made during tests execution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DELETE FROM <tablename>; VACCUUM;` or drop the table(s) and recreate.  Use the later if you need to reset sequence values used by AUTOINCREMENT columns.

Comment: None of these reverts the changes, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, by 'clean' I thought you meant empty. You're looking for a way to get back to an initial state where the database isn't empty?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909221/android-sqlite-rollback) has some answers that might lead you in the right direction.  Using transactions to handle the rollback for you would be the easiest I would think.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would bo to create a mock DB has only some test data, after the test simply drop it.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent Note Pad sample application does something like this. It includes unit tests for the content provider that Note Pad uses. Since these tests are based on JUnit 3, the
setUp() and tearDown() methods are called for each unit test.

The test methods make use of a private method in the content provider to drop the tables in the underlying database and then recreate them. The test class and the content provider class use the same package name, so the private method is visible to the test. It's not visible outside the content provider, though, so nobody else should be able to call it, and it doesn't have Javadoc.

If this doesn't suffice, you can use the ContentProvider.call() method to control the provider (by calling ContentResolver.call()).