# How to rollback deleted row in android sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm adding a item in a cart,it check in cart is product exist or not by the product_id,if product exist, it updates qty and if not add product,In Cart Activity  pending button is also there,User can make cart pending or activity,when user click on pending button from cart Activity,cart will be clear and  in pending activity cart1 will show  in pending and then when next user adds item in cart than second cart will show active.

But in my case:-cart1 goes in pending and data also clear from the activity but when trying to add item in cart from cart activity,it ask do u want to update?and not able to create the second cart.

how i am doing this task:-
1.while inserting data in cart as well  inserting data in pending table with index_id with is foreign key if index_id will exist then not repeat the index_id if not index_id will be 2 while insert the 2nd cart.

but i think this problem is solve by doing the rollback command, when user makes cart1 pending,data will delete by pend_id and when user click on cart1 active button,then rollback command will execute and cart item will be add.

how will i execute this code i don't know i have tried the code but it's not working

```
     public void PendingCart(int p_id,String status){
         final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         try{ db.beginTransaction();
        String update ="Update PendingCart set status=? where status=?";
        String delete = "Delete from PendingCart where P_ID=?";
        String insert= "Select * from PendingCart where P_ID=?";
        String rollback= "rollback";
        db.execSQL(update,new String[]{String.valueOf( status )});
       db.execSQL(delete,new String[]{String.valueOf( p_id )});
        db.execSQL(insert,new String[]{String.valueOf( p_id )});
        db.execSQL( rollback);
//      db.execSQL(insert,new String[]{String.valueOf( p_id )});
         // db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}finally 
   {db.endTransaction();
         }}
       public List<PendingModel>GetCart_list(){  
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       List<PendingModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
       String query= "Select 
 CART.CART_ID,CART.prod_id,CART.Index_id,CART.Barcode,CART.Amount,CART.Grand 
_Total,CART.Quantity,CART.Price,CART.status,PendingCart.P_ID,PendingCart.sta 
us,PendingCart.Created_Date,PRODUCT.Product_Price,Prod_quantity,PRODUCT.PricType,PRODUCT.Item_Name,PRODUCT.Image,PRODUCT.CGST,PRODUCT.SGST from PRODUCT 
       join CART ON CART.prod_id= PRODUCT.prod_id inner join PendingCart ON  
        PendingCart.Customer_ID = CART.Index_id where CART.Index_Id= 
       PENDINGCART.Customer_Id AND PendingCart.status = CART.status";
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( query,null);
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()){try {
       do {
       PendingModel rp = new PendingModel();
       rp.setC_ID( Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString( 0 ) ) );
       rp.setP_id( Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString( 1 ) ) );
        rp.setIndex( cursor.getInt( 2 ));
        rp.setC_barcode(cursor.getString( 3 ));
        rp.setC_Amount( cursor.getFloat( 4) );
        rp.setGrand_Total( cursor.getFloat( 5 ) );
        rp.setC_qunanity( cursor.getFloat( 6) );
        rp.setC_price( cursor.getFloat( 7 ));


 rp.setstatus( cursor.getString( 8 ));
 rp.setP_ID( cursor.getInt( 9 ) ) ;
  rp.setC_status( cursor.getString( 10) );
  rp.setCreated_Date( cursor.getString( 11));
    rp.setP_price( cursor.getFloat( 12 ) )
           rp.setP_quantity( cursor.getFloat( 13) );
       rp.setP_pricetype( cursor.getString( 14 ) );
       rp.setP_name( cursor.getString( 15 ));
      rp.setP_image( cursor.getString( 16 ))

    rp.setP_cgst( cursor.getInt(17 ) );
    rp.setP_sgst( cursor.getInt(18 ) );list.add( rp );} 
    while (cursor.moveToNext());} catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e( "Error", String.valueOf( e ) );
     } finally {
     cursor.close();
     db.close(); } }
    return list}
```

Comment: checked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909221/android-sqlite-rollback

Comment: @peco getting error in   db.endTransaction();not perform this operation because there is no current transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    db.beginTransaction();
    // your sql stuff
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // do some error handling
} finally {
   db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: hey i tried by using this but it's not working...i think u haven't seen my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to look closely at the log even if the App doesn't appear to fail.

You effectively use

```
db.execSQL("Update PendingCart set status=? where status=?",new String[]{String.valueOf( status )});
```

There are two placeholders **?**'s, so 2 parameters would be expected in the array, you only pass 1 parameter as per `new String[]{String.valueOf( status )}`

- I believe this would result in an exception (trapped because you are within a try/catch/finally construct). However, the eception would be recorded in the log.

Even if that weren't an issue and the placeholders were replaced with the parameter, then you'd be saying ***UPDATE EVERY ROW THAT HAS A STATUS OF whatever BY CHANGING THE STATUS FROM whatever TO whatever*** (i.e. do nothing).
I suspect that you mean to use :-

```
String update ="Update PendingCart set status=? where P_ID=?";
.....
db.execSQL(update,new String[]{status,String.valueOf( p_id )});
```

Which then becomes ***UPDATE THE ROWS where the P_ID column is whatever_the_2nd parameter_is BY CHANGING THE STATUS COLUMN TO the_new_status_as_per_the_first_parameter***

The delete appears to be fine (other than you update the row(s) and then delete the rows you've just updated)

The insert isn't going to insert anything it's a SELECT query as per `String insert= "Select * from PendingCart where P_ID=?";` and even if it works the result (Cursor) isn't used.

Then if the all the above do not fail you undo all the changes by rolling back. If an exception is encountered, as you don;t set the transaction as successful, the all changes will be rolled back when you end the transaction.

So effectively the **PendingCart** method appears to be unable to do anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer dear i have been solved it not using the rollback ,because i have a multiple table linked with each other table,in that case if i used rollback it can effect my other table also that's why i have just used the simple method.which worked for me.